# Select all between date and date (other format) in sql / php

Tags: php, sql

This is the format in the column "date":

```
2011-08-03 13:36:19
```

What i wish to do is make a sql query where it selects all entrys between two dates.

My two dates comes from a datepicker:

from 2011-09-20 to 2011-09-25

Now I cant do `WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-09-20' AND '2011-09-25'`

Because there is also time in the column date, as you can see above.

So how can i do this? Can i do `BETWEEN 2011-09-20 00:00:00 AND 2011-09-25 00:00:00` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the 25th, you'd have to go

```
BETWEEN '2011-09-20 00:00:00' AND '2011-09-25 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question: zero fill the time.  It makes sense, since `00:00:00` is midnight, and indicates the moment one day switches to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Those two conditions are logically equivalent (although your second one has a syntax error as you are missing the single quotes).

You probably mean to add the time to the end date. You'll want to add `23:59:59` to denote the end of the day so it includes all times during that day.

You can do so by appending your end date string (assuming it is POST data from a form with an input name of end_date).

```
$end_date = $_POST['end_date'] . ' 23:59:59';
```

**Note:** Don't forget about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).